# Sails JS : How to choose model name dynamically in controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to write a logic in the controller where I want to use either of the two collections based on request parameters. I have two models ( say abc and xyz ). Both have exactly the same structure. Now if my request contains parameter 'abc' == 1 then I want to use abc otherwise I want to use xyz. How can I do this ?

Let me try to explain with pseudocode what I am trying to accomplish.

```
var collectionToUse = <xyz collection Object> // By default use this collection

if ( req.params.abc == 1 ){
    collectionToUse = <abc collection Object>
}

collectionToUse.find()
```

I know this might be pretty basic but I could not find anything related to this online ?

Comment: Resolved I was using strings instead of actual objects... feeling stupid.. Sorry for posting such question. I am an absolute beginner